# Jquery plugin tinysort isn't working, not sure why

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

This is the [live site](http://tammymealplan.com) I'm messing around with.

The numbers which are on each picture are called via get_field() using php. (I'm using plugin "Advanced custom fields" to create a field where I enter a number when creating a post, in this case it's the protein amount. Then I call it with php so that it displays on top of picture like so:

```
<?php
$protein = get_field('grams_of_protein');
?>

<div class="portfoliooverlay"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><span class="jrm-protein"><?php echo "$protein"; ?></span></a></div>
```

I added a span class of .jrm-protein so that I can target the spans of all the visible posts on the page since they all have the same html structure and all contain .jrm-protein.

I am trying to use the jquery plugin [TinySort](http://tinysort.sjeiti.com/)

The button in the sidebar on the site labeled "sort" has the following JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

jQuery('#sorting-button').click(function() {
        jQuery('.jrm-protein').tsort();
    });
});
```

**Can someone take a look at the site, and figure out why it isn't working?**

I didn't register the plugin script, just enqueued it like this in my functions.php

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'jrm-custom-tinysortjs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jrmcustomtinysort.js', array('jquery'), false );
wp_enqueue_script( 'jrm-customjs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jrmcustom.js', array('jquery'), false );
```

On a side note, I added an overlay to the entire page that toggles when the button is clicked, just to make sure and show you that the JS file is working. Or at least the second one is.

## =================================================================================

**Update: I added a div with a bunch of spans at the bottom, and it works with those, so I guess the question is how can i get it to work across different containers? Should just be a selector issue (but not sure how to do it)**

Answer (score 0):

I don't plan on debugging your whole site, but I'll help with the first error I see:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getElementsByTagName' of null`

```
var container = document.getElementById( 'site-navigation' ),
    button    = container.getElementsByTagName( 'h1' )[0],
    menu      = container.getElementsByTagName( 'ul' )[0];
```

You're setting container to a single element, not the `document` object. Either change `container` on the other 2 lines to `document` or change

```
var container = document.getElementById( 'site-navigation' ),
```

to

```
var container = document,
```

Comment: thanks for that, it was an error in the theme JS. But my main concern is what I described above. I'm thinking it is the way I selected what is to be sorted. Not sure that tinysort will sort spans in different containers.